# Can't add my custom app to i3 search bar (mod+d) using .desktop file

Tags: i3-wm

I installed an executable (godot in my exemple), I want to start it in an other way than going to the terminal and executing the executable.

I am using i3 so I want to add it to my search bar results (mod+d), from what I searched it is using .desktop files from those 2 locations:

*/usr/share/applications/*

*~/.local/share/applications/*

So i tried adding a *godot.desktop* to both those locations and restart my PC but none of them work.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=godot
Exec=/home/tetratrux/Apps/Godot_v4.1.3-stable_linux.x86_64
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
```

I can't take a screenshot but when i type "godot" in my search bar nothing comes up. I have been roaming i3 docs and .desktop eplanations for hours but I still can't wrap my head about why it is not showing up.

PS: Sorry for the tags but I couldn't find better ones :/